# Bootstrap classes with django-registration

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-registration

So, I am doing my first project with django-registration, and I have my default project where I have settings etc, and then templates/registration. At login.html, I simply extend base and put `form.as_p`, as shown below:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Submit' %}" />
</form>
```

But it doesn't look good because it doesn't have bootstrap classes on it. How can I apply bootstrap to this default forms? Do I have to create a new app and new forms? What would you suggest?

Comment: You can use [`django-bootstrap3`](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3) which integrates bootstrap 3 with django.

Comment: Another option you might want to look at is [crispy forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)